# Nesting of rcu_read_locks

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking, rcu

I store a RCU protected pointer `MyStruct *`, in a RCU protected hashtable `MyHash`. When reading/updating `MyStruct` via hashtable, I do as shown below.

```
rcu_read_lock() /* For hashtable 'MyHash' */
hash_for_each_possible_rcu(MyHash, obj, member, key)
{
    rcu_read_lock(); /* For RCU protected data(MyStruct*) stored in hashtable */
    Mystruct* s = rcu_dereference_pointer(obj->s);
    if(s) 
    {
        s->read++;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock(); /* For RCU protected data(MyStruct*) stored in hashtable */
}
rcu_read_unlock() /* For hashtable 'MyHash'*/
```

Note that `MyStruct` is itself part of another RCU protected list ( i.e it is a RCU protected node of another list), which is stored in `MyHash` for faster lookup.

As I understand, `rcu_read_lock`'s are required to make sure any writer update doesn't free up memory until all read-side critical sections are complete. So, is it really necessary to nest `rcu_read_lock`'s or just having the outer `rcu_read_lock`/`rcu_read_unlock` is sufficient?

IOW, since RCU locks are not tied to any single object, do we really need nested rcu locks when accessing multiple RCU protected objects together?

Comment: There is only a **single object** corresponded to RCU read lock. So its effect doesn't depend from the number of nested `rcu_read_lock()`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so to make it clear I made an edit to my question. `MyStruct` is itself part of another RCU protected list i.e it is a RCU protected node in another list and this node pointer is stored my `MyHash` for fast lookups. Each of `MyHash` node is RCU protected as well. So essentially there are two RCU protected objects here.

From my understanding(correct me if wrong), since RCU locks are not tied to any single object, do we need nested rcu locks when accessing multiple RCU protected objects together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nested `rcu_read_lock()` is **not required**.

Similar to other "nested" critical sections, the only effect of nested `rcu_read_lock` is increment of the lock level. That is, futher `rcu_read_unlock` does not immediately end critical section but just revert lock level back.

However, supporting nested locking is treated as an **advantage** of RCU locking mechanism. Having supported nested operations one may develop components *independently* one from others.

E.g., you may have `object_increment` function which can be safely called without RCU lock:

```
void object_increment(Object obj)
{
    rcu_read_lock();
    Mystruct* s = obj->s;
    if(s) 
    {
        s->read++;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
}
```

Then call this function under RCU lock:

```
rcu_read_lock(); /* For hashtable 'MyHash' */
hash_for_each_possible_rcu(MyHash, obj, member, key)
{
    // It is perfectly valid to use the function even with RCU lock already taken
    object_increment(obj);
}
rcu_read_unlock(); /* For hashtable 'MyHash'*/
```

Simple design is almost always outweigh small performance hit from the nested calls to `rcu_read_lock`.

---

Without nested calls allowed one would need to implement another component's function for access with RCU lock:

```
void object_increment_locked(Object obj)
{
    Mystruct* s = obj->s;
    if(s) 
    {
        s->read++;
    }
}
```

and carefully choose which function - locked or non-locked - to use in concrete situations:

```
rcu_read_lock(); /* For hashtable 'MyHash' */
hash_for_each_possible_rcu(MyHash, obj, member, key)
{
    // Already have a lock taken, so use _locked version of the function.
    object_increment_locked(obj);
}
rcu_read_unlock(); /* For hashtable 'MyHash'*/
```